# What does the three schema architecture of DBMS refer to?

Tags: database-theory, databases

This architecture contains three layers or levels of the database management system:

- External level
- Conceptual level
- Internal level

Can some one explain to me with a practical real example so that i can understand this?

Before constructing a data model does enterprise's architects consider to make a three schema architecture of DBMS. But I am totally confused with this abstract model.